# Location API Disclaimer

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, location

I recently had an application fail on section 2.7.2 The details are around the location data information not being disaplayed.

I assume this means that a disclaimer is required for applications that use location API services.

However, I am unable to find the required wording for this disclaimer and would like to know exactly what is required.

I was hoping to use a MessageBox.Show to pop up when the map button is pressed, will this be sufficient?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to allow the user to turn it off at any time. A way could could do this would to be to store a flag in `IsolatedStorage` which indicates that you've gotten the user's permission.

```
MapButtonClicked(...)
{
    if (!Settings.HasSetting("allowLocation") || 
        !((bool)Settings.GetSetting("allowLocation"))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Allow app to use your location?, "Location Services",MessageBoxButtons.OkCancel);
    }
    //handle result
    else
    {
        StartLocationSearch();
    }
}
```

And on a Settings page:

```
<CheckBox x:Name=cbLocationAllow />



cbLocationAllowChecked(...)
{
    Settings.SetSetting("allowLocation", true);
}

cbLocationAllowUnchecked(...)
{
    Settings.SetSetting("allowLocation", false);
}
```

Comment: Great, thanks for that. Its odd though, as I have other apps that use location data and they never failed before.

Comment: Yeah, maybe its not completely required -- but it's definitely a better experience for a user (who perhaps didn't mean to turn it on in the first place) to let them turn it off.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like it,
Most disclaimers come in the form of a pop-up or so on. i used a pop-up for a disclaimer at one point too. they passed it, so i don't see why it wouldn't work for yours too.

Comment: Cheers for the response.Any idea on the specfic wording required for this Location Data disclaimer? 2.7.2 on the M$ check sheet.

Comment: i ended up writing a Custom Disclaimer for everything, haven't had a problem with that.

Comment: Did you put it in your app description? or as a Message Box?

Comment: i used this http://www.silverlight.net/archives/videos/creating-a-custom-popup-in-windows-phone-7  that link should help you out.